# Flash audio visualizer with computeSpectrum has stopped working

Tags: flash

Has something been changed in Flash? I made a music visualizer not long ago for a website I am developing. It uses SoundMixer.computeSpectrum to grab the levels of all the frequencies in the audio. It was working great for me, it was even playing audio from other flash objects on the page which worked fine for me and saved me the trouble of trying to somehow pipe the audio from various player objects to the visualizer.

Well now it doesn't work anymore. I have made changes to the website since I last tested it but I don't think that is the issue. The visualizer no longer has any response to any audio even from within the same flash instance. But when I do play audio within the visualizer, in any browser the framerate noticeably drops. If I preview the swf from the Flash Professional CS3, which uses Flash Player 9 it works fine but for Flash 11.3 in the browser it doesn't. Can someone explain what has changed and what I need to do to make things work?

Update:

Here are some of the pertinent bits of code.

```
var ba:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,timerHandler);

function timerHandler(event:Event):void {   
   SoundMixer.computeSpectrum(ba, true);

}
```

I also use readFloat and writeFloat with the byte array. Of course there is plenty of other code but it all works fine in Flash 9.

Comment: Could you share some code or url? Maybe looking at those could help narrow this down.

Comment: Does it playing in the Flash Player10.2 in Flash Professional CS5 or CS5.5 or CS6?

Comment: I don't have access to flash 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

I've had a same problem and am working hard to fix it.

I have references and would you mind to take a look at those?

Adobe Forums: SoundMixer.computeSpectrum () can't work http://forums.adobe.com/thread/67089

Kirupa Forums: Sound on timeline: SoundMixer.computeSpectrum http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?329632-Sound-on-timeline-SoundMixer-computeSpectrum

**EDIT ON 2012/09/30**

When you declare the `Sound` instantiation, if you have coded it like this:

`var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("url"));`

Where sound is the name of the `Sound` instance, and url being the URL of the sound you are loading, change it to:

`var sound:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("url"), new SoundLoaderContext(0, true));`

That should work.

Comment: I appreciate that you have a similar problem as me but this isn't an answer. You should have posted this as a comment. I tried your Kirupa code and I got a 0 even from ctrl-enter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a defect that began in flash v11.3 causing computeSpectrum() to return incomplete and empty data. It has yet to be fixed in the latest flash player release (v11.5 as of this writing).

If you downgrade to flash player to v11.2, you will see your visualizations work like they used to.

https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3222042

Please vote on this bug so adobe fixes it!!!

---EDIT---
Now fixed as of flash player 11.7!